# Excel export batch of columns from one worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, csv

I am a very new user to VBA and am trying to create a macro to do a batch export of selected columns to a csv and then increment and loop that selection to continue exporting csv until end of dataset.

I have a large Excel worksheet with 1872 columns. I want to select and export columns 1-6 as a csv and then repeat this process for columns 7-12, 13-18 etc until the end of the entire worksheet.

All of the data is in one worksheet, there are no null values in any of the rows or columns.

So in total I would like to end up with 312 csv files.

I have started with recording a Macro as follows, but am unsure how to increment this and loop the code until the end of the dataset.

Thank you very much for any input or help with this question.

```
    Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:F").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\Users\Glen\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Glen\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\EMN_001.csv", FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get the `?`... this way I wish you luck... you can do it :)

Comment: I guess I want to run some sort of batch export that exports data based on a range within the worksheet.

I can manually do this process, but it would involve selecting the first 6 columns, copying and pasting to a new worksheet and then saving as csv. Then repeating the process for columns 7-12, 13-18, etc. etc.

Comment: Or if there is a way I can split the data based on a range and then I can do a batch export using Kutools for Excel

Comment: Why not recording this action with the build in macro recorder?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks DavidPostill, thanks for the update. I am a very inexperienced user to VBA, I am experimenting with recording a Macro to do this in addition to working with the code Gary's Student has provided below. I am just trying to paste the code that I am working with

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for the **first** *.csv* file:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim K As Long, N As Long, i As Long
   K = 1
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, K).End(xlUp).Row
   Close #1
   Open "C:\TestFolder\whatever.csv" For Output As #1
      For i = 1 To N
         st = Cells(i, K).Text
         For j = K + 1 To K + 5
            st = st & "," & Cells(i, j).Text
         Next
         Print #1, st
      Next i
   Close #1
End Sub
```

You will need to modify it to loop over `k` to get the rest of the files.

Comment: Hi Gary's Student,

Comment: Hi Gary's Student

Thank you so much for the code. That worked for the first iteration, I am now just trying to loop over your code for a further 312 iterations. I haven't used VBA much and am not sure if my loop is referring to the correct part of the formula.

Comment: My edit with loop is:

Sub dural()
    Dim K As Long, N As Long, i As Long
    Do While N < 312
    K = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, K).End(xlUp).Row
    Close #1
    Open "D:\Glen Documents\Work\Securologica\Data\CSV\EMN_001.csv" For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To N
    st = Cells(i, K).Text
    For j = K + 1 To K + 5
        st = st & "," & Cells(i, j).Text
            Next
            Print #1, st
        Next i
    Close #1
    Loop
End Sub

Comment: Do I need to change K to an integer?

And also I apologize, how do I paste my code like your above? Mine is just in the comments and hasn't pasted correctly. Thanks

Comment: @Glen - Since you're posting code you've tried, edit it into your original post.  If you DO want to post code, just put a single tick, ` ,on both sides.